# Lapply within a lappy in R

Tags: r, list, dplyr, apply, lapply

LApply-ception?
Anyway.

I have a list which is a list of dataframes. I go through it and make adjustments just fine. However I need to lapply each individual dataframe, that is, iterate through each dataframe in the list.

[image]

So The following works.

```
#THIS WORKS
bottleneck_fury <- function(bottleneck2) {
  
  bottleneck2 <- bottleneck2 %>% 
    mutate(startTime = as_datetime(startTime, tz = "")) %>% 
    mutate(endTime = as_datetime(endTime, tz = "")) %>% 
    mutate(early_startTime = startTime - 300) %>% #5 min prior
    mutate_at(c("startTime", "endTime", "early_startTime"),anytime) %>%  #formatted time
    mutate(id = rownames(bottleneck2)) 
  
  bottleneck2 
}

all_necks <- lapply(bottleneck_test, bottleneck_fury)
dd <- all_necks[[1]]


OUTPUT
dd <- structure(list(startTime = structure(c(1533122400, 1533132060, 
1533151920, 1533205740, 1533207960), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = ""), endTime = structure(c(1533131340, 1533132540, 
1533153300, 1533207660, 1533218460), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = ""), impact = c(627.06, 26.53, 24.34, 166.84, 761.39
), impactPercent = c(1444.6, 33.98, 30.98, 320.75, 1632.12), 
    impactSpeedDiff = c(25814.55, 806.43, 733.5, 6289.26, 30350.4
    ), maxQueueLength = c(4.829494, 3.605648, 2.241074, 5.760513, 
    5.760513), tmcs = list(c("110N04623", "110-04623", "110N04624", 
    "110-04624", "110N04625", "110-04625", "110N04626", "110-04626"
    ), c("110N04623", "110-04623", "110N04624", "110-04624", 
    "110N04625", "110-04625"), c("110N04623", "110-04623", "110N04624", 
    "110-04624"), c("110N04623", "110-04623", "110N04624", "110-04624", 
    "110N04625", "110-04625", "110N04626", "110-04626", "110N04627"
    ), c("110N04623", "110-04623", "110N04624", "110-04624", 
    "110N04625", "110-04625", "110N04626", "110-04626", "110N04627"
    )), early_startTime = structure(c(1533122100, 1533131760, 
    1533151620, 1533205440, 1533207660), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), id = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5")), row.names = c(NA, 
5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Now that I pull this dataframe out and manipulate it, I want to run a loop on it. However the result is a list when I need it to be a dataframe. The second lapply here is now changed to represent the actual case and why unlist() wont work.

```
#DOESNT WORK
bottleneck_fury <- function(bottleneck2) {
  
 # bottleneck2 <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(bottleneck), nrow=length(bottleneck), byrow=T))
  
  bottleneck2 <- bottleneck2 %>% 
    mutate(startTime = as_datetime(startTime, tz = "")) %>% 
    mutate(endTime = as_datetime(endTime, tz = "")) %>% 
    mutate(early_startTime = startTime - 300) %>% #5 min prior
    mutate_at(c("startTime", "endTime", "early_startTime"),anytime) %>%  #formatted time
    mutate(id = rownames(bottleneck2)) 
  
  bottleneck2 
  #md_events2 <-  md_events 
  
  
  test <- lapply(1:nrow(bottleneck2), function(x) {
    #go row by row
    bottleneck_row <- bottleneck2[x,]
    events <- iris[which(bottleneck_row$maxQueueLength < iris$Petal.Length ==TRUE),]

    ID <- do.call("rbind",replicate(nrow(events), bottleneck_row, simplify = FALSE))
    cbind(events, ID)
}

}

all_necks <- lapply(bottleneck_test, bottleneck_fury)
dd <- all_necks[[1]]
View(dd)
```

My wish here is that R can do the lapply within the lapply and give me a new dataframe for both of my dataframes in the list.

In the end, dd should be a dataframe which is the first dataframe in the list `all_necks`.

Comment: 1) You have two functions with the same name, the problem is with the 2nd one? 2) The data set is `dd` after running the first function?

Comment: Problem is #2, and yes that's dd after the working function

Comment: Can you share your original data `bottleneck_test`  and show expected output?

Comment: Even a subset is too large but happy to do so over a private message in a chatroom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the data frames you are using are not large, it is preferable to integrate the data frames into one and identifying them with an id. This makes the procedure much more efficient. You can do this with the "ldply" function of the "plyr" package that can integrate files in a specific folder that you can select according to a pattern that follows the name of the files. You can do this applying a function to each file. In your case, you can do it in the following way:

```
library(plyr)
setwd("~/directory")
all_necks<- ldply(.data = list.files(pattern = "some-pattern"),   .fun = function(x){
              y<-read.csv(x,header=T) 
              y$ID <- x 
              y
              } ### The function read the file and creates a new column that stores a unique ID for each file.
)
```

The second part I understand that you try to identify the observations of the data frame "iris" that are greater for each value of the variable "maxQueueLength" in the data frame "events". Then you replicate nrow (events) times each observation of the data.frame bottleneck2 and store it in the variable ID; I don't quite understand what the purpose of doing this is. But you can do it in a more efficient way without using for loops (it is a good idea to avoid using them as much as possible and also lapply or sapply, because they are no longer more efficient than these, obviously this will not always be possible).

One strategy to avoid using them is to extend your data frame “all necks” to the number of rows that the for loop you used would generate, which would be the product of nrow (iris), that meet the condition you specified, multiplied by nrow (all_necks). Although, to prevent you from checking the compliance of your condition in values ​​of the variable “maxQueueLength” several times, instead of having nrow (all_necks) it will have length (unique (all_necks$maxQueueLength)), in the code this was done with the function "distinct "from dplyr. Before doing this you add the variable "Sepal.Length" with added NAs in "all_necks" so that it has the same length () as "all_necks".
Once you have the data frame integrated, use the group_by () function to group by the variable "maxQueueLength". Each group has the length () of the dataframe "iris", this in order to make the comparison between each value of "Petal.Length" with each value of "maxQueueLength". To finish, you use mutate () to check the condition for each combination of values ​​and that's it. The result should be data.frame and it should take considerably less time to execute.

```
library(dplyr)

nrow_iris <- nrow(iris)
nrow_necks<- nrow(all_necks)

all_necks<- all_necks %>% add_column(Sepal_length = c(iris$Sepal.Length,rep(NA,nrow_necks-nrow_iris)) )
all_necks_2 <- all_necks %>% distinct(maxQueueLength,.keep_all = T)
all_necks_2 <- do.call("rbind",replicate(nrow_iris*length(all_necks_2$maxQueueLength),all_necks,simplify = F ))

all_necks_2<- all_necks_2 %>% group_by(maxQueueLength) %>% mutate(new=maxQueueLength < Petal.Length) %>% ungroup()
all_necks_2 %>% count(vars = new)
```